# Unable to access global variable in included file

Tags: php, include, scope, global-variables

I am having an unexpected issue with scope. The [`include` documentation](http://php.net/include) (also applies to `require_once`) says the required file should have access to all variable at the line it was required.

For some reason I am not able to access a class instantiated with global scope inside a function that was required in.

Would anyone know why? I am obviously missing something.

I got it working through a reference to `$GLOBALS[]`, but I still want to know why it is not working.

**UPDATE:**

The error I am getting is:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function isAdmin() on a non-object in <path>.php on <line>
```

Code:

```
$newClass = new myClass();

require_once("path to my file");

----- inside required file -----
function someFunction() {
     $newClass->someMethod(); // gives fatal error. (see above).
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Functions define a new scope, so inside a function you cannot access variables in the global scope.

[Variable Scope](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

> within user-defined functions a local
>   function scope is introduced. Any
>   variable used inside a function is by
>   default limited to the local function
>   scope

About included files, [the manual states](http://hu2.php.net/manual/en/function.include.php):

> When a file is included, the code it
>   contains inherits the variable scope
>   of the line on which the include
>   occurs.

So if you include something in a function, the included file's scope will be that of the function's.

**UPDATE:** Looking at your code example edited into the question, `global $newClass;` as the first line of the function should make it working.

```
$newClass = new myClass();
require_once("path to my file");

----- inside required file -----
function someFunction() {
     global $newClass;
     $newClass->someMethod(); 
}
```

Be aware though that using `global` can quickly make your code more difficult to maintain. Don't rely on the global scope, you can pass the object to the function as a parameter, or use a Singleton/Registry class (some tend to argue against the latter, but depending on the case it can be a cleaner solution).

Comment: I even tried calling global $myClass; Did not work. It did work with $GLOBALS["myClass"].

Comment: Looking at your code example edited into the question, `global $newClass;` as the first line of the function should make it working.

Comment: @John, `global $myClass` (or `global $newClass` in your example above) should work as it would normally. I just tested it now and it's in no way different than if the function would be defined in the main script.

Comment: bazmegakapa: Thank you. I defined a local var as "global (refTObj)" then used the local.

Answer (score 2):

The included code doesn't have a scope different than the code surrounding it. For example:

```
function a() {
    echo $b;
}
```

This will fail even if `echo $b` is in an included file. If you replace the above with:

```
function a() {
    include 'file.php';
}
```

... and `file.php` contains:

```
echo $b;
```

... then it's the same thing as if you wrote:

```
function a() {
    echo $b;
}
```

Think of it this way: whenever you use `include` / `require`, the contents of the included file is going to replace the `include` / `require` statement, just as if you removed the statement and pasted the contents of the file in its place.

It doesn't do anything else as far as scope is concerned.